# Buttons must have discernible text: Element has no title attribute

Tags: html, jquery, button, attributes

I was creating a website and I find some problems - so one of this problem is that shown in the picture this  the real problem is that button isn't an html element - I don't have those buttons in my html; it's from owl-carousel.

[image]

How do I get them or how can I fix the problem and thanks

To be clear I didn't try anything because i don't know how to get  to them

Answer (score 2):

Give the button a 'title' attribute and it will disappear. I think it is necessary for accessibility reasons, possibly to explain the purpose of a button. For example, if a button was supposed to logout a user, a screen reader could describe that to them clearly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Some site](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.8/button-name) published the following. Indicated a few solutions, one is the `title` attribute.

> The button-name rule has five markup patterns that pass test criteria:
>
> ````
> <button id="al" aria-label="Name"></button>
>
> <button id="alb" aria-labelledby="labeldiv"></button> <div
> id="labeldiv">Button label</div>
>
> <button id="combo" aria-label="Aria Name">Name</button>
>
> <button id="buttonTitle" title="Title"></button> ```
> ````